# How to add "outside" event listener to Markers in Google Maps (react-google-maps/api)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I have a list of hikes stored in `state` and I rendered the location of those hikes as Markers on the Google Map Component like so:

```
{hikes.map(hike =>
  <Marker        
    position={{lat: hike.coordinates.latitude, lng: hike.coordinates.longitude}}
    icon = {
       { url:"https://static.thenounproject.com/png/29961-200.png",
         scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50,50)
      }
     } 
     onClick={()=>{console.log(hike.name)}}            
  />
```

I also display the list of hikes and its other details in its own `BusinessCard` Component like so:

```
export const Businesses = (props)=>{
    const {hikes, addToTrip} = props
    return(<>
    <div className="businessesColumn">
    {hikes.map(hike=>(
        <BusinessCard.../>  
))}
```

When I hover over each of the `BusinessCard` components, I want the corresponding marker to animate "bounce." I tried manipulate `google.maps.event.addListener` but I think I was doing it wrong. I'm not sure if it can detect events outside of the `GoogleMap` component? Any ideas on how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I don't know exactly how your components are structured, but try adding state `activeMarker` inside the component where your Markers are located. Then pass down `setActiveMarker` as a prop to the `Business` component. And inside the `Business` component, pass down `hike.coordinates.latitude`, `hike.coordinates.longitude` and `setActiveMarker` as props to the `BusinessCard` components. Inside `BusinessCard`, add `onHover={() => props.setActiveMarker({ lat: props.latitude, lng: props.longitude })}`

*Something like this...*

**Component where Markers are located**

```
const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState(null)

return (
  <>
    <GoogleMap>
      {hikes.map(hike => (
        <Marker        
          position={{lat: hike.coordinates.latitude, lng: hike.coordinates.longitude}}
          icon = {{
            url:"https://static.thenounproject.com/png/29961-200.png",
            scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50,50)
          }}
          animation={
            (hike.coordinates.latitude === activeMarker.lat
            && hike.coordinates.longitude === activeMarker.lng)
              ? google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE : undefined
          }            
        />
      ))}
    </GoogleMap>
    <Business setActiveMarker={setActiveMarker} />
  </>
)
```

**Business component**

```
return(
  <div className="businessesColumn">
    {hikes.map(hike => (
      <BusinessCard
        latitude={hike.coordinates.latitude}
        longitude={hike.coordinates.longitude}
        setActiveMarker={props.setActiveMarker}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

**BusinessCard component**

```
return (
  <div
    className="business-card"
    onMouseEnter={() => props.setActiveMarker({ lat: props.latitude, lng: props.longitude })}
  >
    {/* Whatever */}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified it a little bit, for some reason my `animation` didnt know what `BOUNCE` was. Im assuming its because I am using `@react-google-maps/api` anyway this worked for me `animation={ (activeMarker.id === hike.id ? 1 : undefined) }` and i also used `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` as I had child `div`s that was interfering with my hover ... thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help. I thought `animation` was a String but it's actually an Object property `google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE`. And yeah, React doesn't even have onHover. I keep forgetting that haha.